# Get spreadsheet Values and Formulas without spill data from ArrayFormulas

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, array-formulas

I am trying to create a Google Apps Script that will copy the formulas and values from a source sheet and paste them onto a destination sheet.

The method I'm using to get the formula and values is to just use both `getFormulas()` and `getValues()`, and then just merge the arrays to take the formula if one exists, or use the value if there is no formula.

This works for the most part, however, it breaks with ArrayFormulas, since it copies the formula for the cell itself, but will also copy the values from the ArrayFormula spill, which then prevents the ArrayFormula from expanding as it is blocked by the static values.

Is there a way to use getValues or something similar, to only get values which have been entered, and are not the result of an array elsewhere?

I tried looking if the Advanced Sheets Service had anything I could use but couldn't find anything that helps. I really want to avoid having to parse the formulas and find whether or not it's and ArrayFormula, extract the ranges that it spills into, and delete those spill values from the array created from `getFormulas()` and `getValues()` as this would slow down the script to the point it would likely be unusable.

Comment: Yeah I never use ArrayFormula because GS doesn't seem to work with them and I'd much rather have GS than AF

Comment: It seems that it is not possible to tell if a cell value is actually a result from an ArrayFormula, there is no method in the Built-in library nor in the Google Sheets API itself. You would need to create code to find the ranges that the Arrayformula spills into, I'd highly recommend you to report the missing feature as a Feature Request at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191608&template=823917

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ValueRenderOption`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueRenderOption) as `FORMULA` in Advanced Sheets service to get a mix of formulas and values. This option  excludes values that are spilled from  array formulas, but provides values, which are manually filled.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction [The Master](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/themaster)

Here's a code example:

```js
/**
 * Gets the values & formulas from a Range excluding any spillover from
 * array formulas, by using Google's Advanced Sheets Service API.
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75698065/
 * https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueRenderOption
 * 
 * *NOTE* You must add the "Google Sheets" API to your Apps Script
 * project before this function will work, see:
 * https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services
 * 
 * You should probably also handle exceptions in case of a failed request, see:
 * https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets
 * 
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Range} range - The Range to get values from
 * @return {array} - A 2D array of values containing user entered values & formulas, 
 *                   but '' for any cells containing array formula splillover.
 */
function getValuesWithoutArrayFormulaSpillover(range) {
  const rangeString = range.getSheet().getName() + '!' + range.getA1Notation();
  const spreadsheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
  return Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, rangeString, {valueRenderOption: "FORMULA"}).values;
}
```

Comment: This solution is exactly what I'm looking for.   What should I enter into the range, if I want to get from A1:B4 from the current active sheet?  For instance, range = 'A1:B4'?